# how to implode multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to implode this array:

```
$name;
foreach ($childs as  $cval) {
  $name[] = $cval;
}
```

And here is what I got:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [pages_name] => services child 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [pages_name] => services child 2
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [pages_name] => inner service child 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [pages_name] => inner service child 2
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [pages_name] => gallery child 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [pages_name] => gallery child 2
            )

    )

)
```

I'm doing this with `array_map` like this:

```
$arr = array_map(function($el){ return $el['pages_name']; }, $name);

$str = implode(',', $arr);
```

And I got this error:

```
Undefined index: pages_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten a depth level, try this:

```
$arr = array_map(function($el){ return $el[0]['pages_name']; }, $name);
```